# gradle run tests against obfuscated jar

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, proguard

gradle: how to run tests against obfuscated jar?

```
src/main/java
src/test/java

gradle test
```

It will run tests against the main source set output, not jar.

Suppose:

```
the main.jar is obfuscated to main-obfuscated.jar.
```

How to run tests against the obfuscated jar, not the main output classes?